finding out the time to live value for a node in Zookeeper
I am able to set the TTL value for a node.
Having said that, is there a way to programmatically find out what the TTL value is for a node that has one?
A reference to the API docs would be just fine as an answer.
At the moment finding out the value is more of a curiosity than a real need.
I am using zookeeper-3.6.4
I have not come across and obvious way to do this.
I have not scoured the api documentation or looked at the source code (yet)
Looking at the documentation for that Stat object, it doesnt appear to be there.
